# What is the CRS for raster::area in R, and why divide by 1 million?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, polygon

To calculate the area of polygon in R I have been using the following code (this is the example code from the package's documentation, mine is modified to contain my data):

`p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))`

`p$area <- round(area(p) / 10000000,1)`

which returns

`p$area`

`312.3 218.7 259.5  76.2 263.2 188.3 129.0 210.4 185.6 251.3 237.1 233.3`

Anyway, these make sense as square km areas of the states of Luxembourg, and when I run this code with my data I get results that makes sense as well.

My question is: what is the CRS?

using `crs(p)` gives me `CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs  Warning message: In proj4string(x) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output`

From other posts I have learned that the warning code is nothing and that raster::area() returns square meters from lat long coordinates (such is the case here). But I was under the impression that WGS84 was a datum, not a CRS, so what is the CRS? Also why do I divide by 1 million? Is raster::area() converting to square millimeters?

Comment: Areas use _squared_ units (km^2), so to convert from one area unit to another we use the _square_ of the linear conversion factor.  A square of 1 km x 1 km (1 km^2) has 1000m x 1000m, which is 1,000,000 m^2.

Comment: Oh. That makes total sense, thanks!

Comment: For your other question, WGS84 is a datum AND a geographic CRS!